# While loop select all contacts

Tags: php, loops, syntax, while-loop

Okay so I have a script that generated pdf reports from a php page for different clients. At the moment this can only handle one client at a time but I would like to add a while statement to be able to cope when 'ALL' clients are picked from the drop down.

The while should select * contacts from mydatabase.mytable and run through the normal code for each. This is the bit I dont know how to do.

I know its something like this but can't quite remember the syntax...

```
<?php
$client_id=$_POST["client_id"];
$date_start=$_POST["date_start"];
$date_end=$_POST["date_end"];

if ($client_id == 'ALL') {

}
else
{
  $command="php myfile.php $client_id $date_start $date_end > myfile.html";
  exec($command, $output, $status);
  if ($status!=0) {print_r($output); die("wget failed with status $status"); }

  $command="wkhtmltopdf-i386 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm myfile.html myfile.pdf";
  exec($command, $output, $status);
  if ($status!=0) die("htmltopdf failed");
}
?>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Paste the code you're using for 1 client, please.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if` control structure would suffice.

```
if ('All' == $client_id) {
    // e.g. - generateReport(-1)
    // Your function would look for -1 so it knows to generate for all
}
else {
    // e.g. - generateReport($client_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select ALL contacts from your database, then you should be able to get back an array of some sort, perhaps something like this:

```
array(
   ['John Smith'] => array( 'company' => 'xyz'),
   ['Anna Citizen'] => array( 'company' => 'abc),
)
```

To generate the above array, you can check for "ALL" contacts:

```
if ($_POST['dropdown'] == "ALL"){
  //generate for ALL
}else{
  //generate for 1 contact
}
```

Then you can use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate through your array for ALL contacts:

```
foreach ($contacts as $contact => $attributes){
  var_dump($contact); //John Smith
  var_dump($attributes); // array('company' => 'xyz);
  var_dump($attributes['company']); //xyz

  //Do whatever to generate reports.
}
```